# Proof that $\mathbb R/[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

On $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, generate an equivalence relation by $x\sim x$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x\sim 0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$.
Prove $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What problems are you having? don't you mean that $x\sim x$ if $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]$ ???

Comment: "$\mathbb{R}/\sim$" is a quotient map.  The quotient is complete before you start examining the homeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

In order to show that $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ its enough to find a map $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is surjective, is a quotient map and $f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $x\sim y$. Define $f$ as 
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \ \begin{cases} 
      x & x\in (-\infty, 0) \\
      0, & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      x-1 & x\in (1,\infty) 
   \end{cases}
\
\end{equation*}

Check that $f$ satisfies the conditions defined above and conclude that $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: is it very difficult to prove that $f$ is a quotient map? Cause I've been trying and I can't.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $X=\mathbb R/\sim$ is $X=\{\{x\}\mid x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{[0,1]\}$ and consider $f:X\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f([0,1])=0$, $f(\{x\})=x$ if $x\lt0$ and $f(\{x\})=x-1$ if $x\gt1$. This is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* You're simply collapsing the unit interval to a point, $0$.